# ASP.NET membership (not MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have some problem. I've been frustrating for a couple of days with setting up my `asp.net` website.

I need my web site to be really portable. I need to have possibility just copy my visual studio solution, give it to someone and he will run it on his local machine without any efforts like installing SQL environment.

Perfect solution for me is to inject some kind of `.mdf` database without using any SQL servers. Does such solution exist? Or may be I should go another way to reach my goal and create ASP.NET membership website?

I am a freshman with asp.net, so please provide as wide answers as you can. Thanks.

Comment: Check out this post: [Using a .MDF SQL Server Database with ASP.NET Versus Using SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631687/using-a-mdf-sql-server-database-with-asp-net-versus-using-sql-server)

Comment: Really, I haven't seen any "versus" there. Only that .mdf in App_Data is sql express server database. I am right?

Comment: The accepted answer says that you can use a MDF file, but it will need to be attached to atleast an SQLExpress instance. Which in turn requires that it is installed on the computer running the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try SQL Server Compact Edition. It does not require SQL Server installed, but it does require the SDK installed. [Down link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=17876)

Comment: thanks, but can you provide some sample how to use it with asp.net (some link to nice study resources?)